# Wordpress Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: json, server

All site ajax returns "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0". Plugins, updates, editor don't work.

Dashbord widget loads home page: [image]
There are no problems on another server.

Comment: And what does the server return for these AJAX requests?

Comment: @krzysiek-dróżdż html of home page

Comment: so it’s not JSON. But AJAX request shouldn’t return html, so something is not ok with your site...